# Fast version of paste

Tags: text-processing, software-rec, paste

`paste` is a brilliant tool, but it is dead slow: I get around 50 MB/s on my server when running:

```
paste -d, file1 file2 ... file10000 | pv >/dev/null
```

`paste` is using 100% CPU according to `top`, so it is not limited by, say, a slow disk.

Looking at the source code it is probably because it uses `getc`:

```
          while (chr != EOF)
            {
              sometodo = true;
              if (chr == line_delim)
                break;
              xputchar (chr);
              chr = getc (fileptr[i]);
              err = errno;
            }
```

Is there another tool that does the same, but which is faster? Maybe by reading 4k-64k blocks at a time? Maybe by using vector instructions for finding the newline in parallel instead of looking at a single byte at a time? Maybe using `awk` or similar?

The input files are UTF8 and so big they do not fit in RAM, so reading *everything* into memory is not an option.

Edit:

thanasisp suggests running jobs in parallel. That improves throughput slightly, but it is still a magnitude slower than pure `pv`:

```
# Baseline
$ pv file* | head -c 10G >/dev/null
10.0GiB 0:00:11 [ 897MiB/s] [>                                           ]  3%            

# Paste all files at once
$ paste -d, file* | pv | head -c 1G >/dev/null
1.00GiB 0:00:21 [48.5MiB/s] [                         <=>                                ]

# Paste 11% at a time in parallel, and finally paste these
$ paste -d, <(paste -d, file1*) <(paste -d, file2*) <(paste -d, file3*) \
  <(paste -d, file4*) <(paste -d, file5*) <(paste -d, file6*) \
  <(paste -d, file7*) <(paste -d, file8*) <(paste -d, file9*) |
    pv | head -c 1G > /dev/null
1.00GiB 0:00:14 [69.2MiB/s] [                 <=>                                        ]
```

`top` still shows that it is the outer `paste` that is the bottleneck.

I tested if increasing the buffer made a difference:

```
$ stdbuf -i8191 -o8191 paste -d, <(paste -d, file1?) <(paste -d, file2?) <(paste -d, file3?)   <(paste -d, file4?) <(paste -d, file5?) <(paste -d, file6?)   <(paste -d, file7?) <(paste -d, file8?) <(paste -d, file9?) |   pv | head -c 1G > /dev/null
1.00GiB 0:00:12 [80.8MiB/s] [              <=>                                           ]
```

This increased throughput 10%. Increasing the buffer further gave no improvement. This is likely hardware dependent (i.e. it may be due to the size of level 1 CPU cache).

Tests are run in a RAM disk to avoid limitations related to the disk subsystem.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `getc()` doesn't necessarily cause data to be read from disk if the data already has been read into a buffer by the I/O library (which may well read 4 KB chunks).

Comment: don't count on `awk`, that's terrible slower than `paste` itself even if you define a custom `RS` that never exist in your file in order to tell awk whole file is a single record, `awk` will still scan whole file from top to down.

Comment: `paste` is generic and it does need to check for the end-of-line character (it does not read one character at time from disk though, there are underlying buffers). Whatever optimization you can do, it will be probably related to specific formatting/content of the input files. Could you share more info on them? Maybe an example?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani The content is UTF-8 text files. No other restrictions.

Comment: I don't think that this could be done faster by one process, keeping 10K files open, and reading them. Also, the standard text-processing tools (awk/sed etc) are expected to be slower, they could be faster only for a few files, loading all lines to memory, paste is fast using no memory. Just an idea, that you maybe have already: some combination of paste commands to run in parallel and paste incrementally, could be a bit faster, it depends on the box maybe (like: paste 100 streams of paste commands on 100 files each).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some further tests with different alternatives and scenarios

(Edit: cutoff values for compiled version supplemented)

## tl;dr:

1. yes, coreutils `paste` is far slower than `cat`
2. there seems no easily available alternative that is uniformly faster than coreutils `paste`, in particular not for lots of short lines
3. `paste` is amazingly stable in throughput across different combinations of line length, number of lines and number of files
4. for longer lines faster alternatives are provided below

## In Detail:

I tested quite a number of scenarios. Throughput measurement was done using `pv` as in the original post.

### Compared Programs:

1. `cat` (from GNU coreutils 8.25 used as baseline)
2. `paste` (also from GNU coreutils 8.25)
3. [python script](https://gist.github.com/joseffrank/65f1cf0554170985fe52c9953dc14e2a) from [answer above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684713/118985)
4. [alternative python script](https://gist.github.com/joseffrank/366712019019440ba778fec0b5252973) (replacing list comprehension for collecting line fragments by regular loop)
5. [nim program](https://gist.github.com/joseffrank/0d06a06270bf6172e91b5c517dbc914c) (akin to 4. but compiled executable)

### File / Line number combinations:

| # | columns | lines |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200,000 | 1,000 |
| 2 | 20,000 | 10,000 |
| 3 | 2,000 | 100,000 |
| 4 | 200 | 1,000,000 |
| 5 | 20 | 10,000,000 |
| 6 | 2 | 100,000,000 |

Total amount of data was the same in each test (1.3GB). Each column consisted of 6-digit numbers (e.g. 000'001 to 200'000).
Above combinations were distributed across 1, 10, 100, 1'000, and 10'000 equally sized files as far as possible.

Files where generated like: `yes {000001..200000} | head -1000 > 1`

Pasting was done like: `for i in cat paste ./paste ./paste2 ./paste3; do $i {00001..1000} | pv > /dev/null; done`

However, the files pasted were actually all links to the same original file, so all data should be in cache anyway (created directly before pasting and read with `cat` first; system memory is 128GB, cache size 34GB)

An additional set was run, where data where created on the fly instead of reading from pre-created files and piped into `paste` (denoted below with number of files=0).

For the last set the command was like `for i in cat paste ./paste ./paste2 ./paste3; do $i <(yes {000001..200000} | head -1000) | pv > /dev/null; done`

### Findings:

1. `paste` is an order of magnitude slower than `cat`
2. `paste`'s throughput is extremely consistent (~300MB/s) across a wide range of line widths, and number of files involved.
3. Home grown python alternatives can show some advantage as soon as average input file line length is above a certain limit (~1400 characters on my test machine).
4. Compiled nim version has about double throughput compared to python scripts. Point of break even in comparison with `paste` is ~500 characters for one input file. This decreases with growing number of input files, down to ~150 characters per input file line as soon as at least 10 input files are involved.
5. Both, python and nim versions, suffer from processing overhead for many short lines (suspected reason: in both the stdlib functions used try to detect line endings and convert them to platform specific endings). coreutils `paste` however is not affected.
6. Seemingly the simultaneous on-the-fly data generation process was the limiting factor for `cat`, as well as for the nim version with longer lines, and also affected processing speed to some extent.
7. At some point the multitude of open file handles seems to have a detrimental impact even on coreutils `paste`. (Just speculating: Maybe this could even affect the parallel version?)

[image]

### Conclusion (at least for test machine)

1. If input files are narrow use coreutils paste, in particular when files are very long.
2. If input files are rather wide, prefer alternative (Input file line length > 1400 characters for python versions, 150-500 characters for nim version depending on number of input files).
3. Generally prefer compiled nim version over python scripts.
4. Beware of too many small fragments. The default soft limit of 1024 open files for a process seems quite reasonable in this context.

### Suggestion for OP's situation (parallel processing)

If input files are narrow, use coreutils `paste` in the inner jobs and [compiled alternative](https://gist.github.com/joseffrank/0d06a06270bf6172e91b5c517dbc914c) for the outermost process. If all files have long lines use nim version generally.

**Cave**: the linked programs are ad-hoc versions, provided as they are, without any guarantees and without explicit error handling. Also separator is hard coded in all three implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Despite getc being highly optimized and nowadays mostly implemented as a buffer backed macro, I'd agree that it may still be the bottleneck - just as you suspect, or rather: the possibly comparably small size of the used buffer, resulting in still a high number of file reads.

While I did not get the exact numbers you showed above, in my tests there is still a marked difference between baseline and paste runs.

(Maybe the culprit is the switches in buffering (blocks for the files, lines for the stream). However I'm not that experienced w.t.r.)

Testing further I got a similar drop in throughput when using the following construct:

```
cat file* | dd | pv > /dev/null
```

Throughput with dd inserted in between was very similar to that of the paste run. (dd by default uses block size of 512 bytes). If further reducing the buffer size, running time increases proportionally. When however increasing the block size to only a few kb (e.g. 8 or 16), speed increased dramatically. When using 1 or 2M it took off:

```
cat file* | dd bs=2M | pv > /dev/null
```

There seems to be a possibility to change buffer size for getc (in case of stdout switch from line to block buffering with freely selected size). However one has to keep in mind that with several 1000s of open files and a buffer for each of them memory requirement goes up quickly.

Nonetheless, one could try to change the buffering (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66219179/usage-of-getc-with-a-file) by using an appropriate setvbuf call and see what will happen.

**Addition**: Presently I'm not aware of a comparable and publicly available program being faster for the same task.

(P.S.: Just read your name - aren't you the GNU parallel guy?
Great piece of work!)

Answer (score 1):

As I have experienced python text processing as comparably fast in the past (i.e. python text processing routines highly optimized and heavily tuned), I just cobbled together a small q&d python script and compared it with paste from coreutils. (Of course this thing is very limited w.r.t. its options as it's only for demonstration purposes (only accepting file names of present files), and column separator is hard wired.)

Put this into a textfile called `paste` in your current directory, provide execute permissions and give it a try.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys
filenames = sys.argv[1:]
infiles = [open(i,'r') for i in filenames]

while True:
    lines = [i.readline() for i in infiles]
    if all([i=='' for i in lines]):
        break
    print("\t".join([i.strip("\n") for i in lines]))
```

**Update:** Fixed a bug in the above script that caused it to abort as soon as the same line was found empty in all input files. Timing measurement for the python version also updated below to reflect actual run time.

On several systems I tested, after warming up the cache (did not bother creating a ramdisk) the **python version above consistently outperformed coreutils paste** by a margin of 10% (Debian Buster native) to 30% (VM running Debian Stretch). On Windows the difference is even more pronounced, that however may be due to additional posix translation overhead or different caching (cygwin with coreutils paste 8.26: >20x slower; msys2 with coreutils paste 8.32: >12x slower than python version; both running python 3.9.9). For these tests I just created a file with 100 very long lines and pasted it to itself, as it seems that the problematic thing is the handling of long lines.

```
jf1@s1 MSYS /d/temp/ui
# time paste b b > /dev/null

real    0m5.920s
user    0m5.896s
sys     0m0.031s

jf1@s1 MSYS /d/temp/ui
# time ../paste b b > /dev/null

real    0m0.480s
user    0m0.295s
sys     0m0.170s

jf1@s1 MSYS /d/temp/ui
# ../paste b b > c1

jf1@s1 MSYS /d/temp/ui
# paste b b > c2

jf1@s1 MSYS /d/temp/ui
# diff c1 c2

jf1@s1 MSYS /d/temp/ui
#
```

Comment: In my parallelized test the above is twice as fast as coreutils' `paste` on my 64 core system. Not `pv` performance, but *clearly* an improvement.

Comment: Did you exchange all instances of paste in this test or only the outermost?

Comment: I exchanged all. The outer one is currently using 100% CPU.

Comment: I can squeeze a few extra MB/s by putting more files in each inner `paste`s. I can get around 100 MB/s.